# Unable to connect to the GDB server through arm-none-eabi-gdb command

Tags: rust, embedded, stm32f4discovery

I am following this [tutorial](https://docs.rust-embedded.org/discovery/05-led-roulette/flash-it.html). I have compiled the code successfully, but when I try to run using command `arm-none-eabi-gdb -q thumbv7em-none-eabihf/debug/led-roulette` on terminal, it says that:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\8 2018-q4-major\bin\arm-none-eabi-gdb.exe: warning: Couldn't determine a path for the index cache directory.
thumbv7em-none-eabihf/debug/led-roulette: No such file or directory
```

Although, I have physically checked the path and the file does exist there.

I am a beginner to stm32f3Discovery and trying to setup the device using the [documentation](https://docs.rust-embedded.org/discovery/)

Steps taken so far:

1. Already added the target using:
   `rustup target add thumbv7em-none-eabihf`
2. Compiled the program using command:
   `cargo build --target thumbv7em-none-eabihf`
3. Getting correct output of the following command:
   `cargo readobj --target thumbv7em-none-eabihf --bin led-roulette -- -file-headers`
4. As I am on Windows, I've tried the following command to launch openOCD:
   `openocd -s C:\OpenOCD\scripts -f interface/stlink-v2-1.cfg -f target/stm32f3x.cfg`
5. Run this command to connect to gdb server, but failed:
   `arm-none-eabi-gdb -q target/thumbv7em-none-eabihf/debug/led-roulette`

The above command should work and connect GDB server, but it doesn't.

Comment: The error message shows a different path thatn you wrote in your "steps taken so far". Triple check, that you are in the correct folder and the relative path is correct. Use an absolute path if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks hellow.. Your 'Triple check' statement works for me. Yes, it was the path issue which i had to change while debugging. It is rocking..